# Can a dataset be stationary and show seasonality when building an ARIMA/SARIMAX model?

Tags: python, time-series, arima, sarimax

I was evaluating and building an ARIMA/SARIMAX model for sales forecasting. When I ran the Adfuller test for my dataset I got the following results -

```
ADF Test Statistic : -4.973173618997548
p-value : 2.507235653612757e-05
#Lags Used : 0
Number of Observations Used : 51
{'1%': -3.5656240522121956,
 '5%': -2.920142229157715,
 '10%': -2.598014675124952}
```

And when I ran `seasonal_decompose` for my dataset I got the following results -

[image: Seasonal Decompose Output for Product ID: 111063]

The `seasonal_decompose` output clearly shows a seasonality as seen in the 'Seasonal' graph however the values of Adfuller test conclude that the data is Stationary. I was wondering if the dataset can be seasonal as well as stationary? I am confused whether to use ARIMA or SARIMAX model in this case.

My view is that the data appears stationary because the mean of the series might not be varying across seasons. I might be wrong. Please provide your inputs on this. Thanks!

Comment: I found this post similar to the doubt I have - 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63242812/why-my-time-series-use-seasonal-decompose-can-see-clear-seasonal-but-when-app?rq=2

Based on this I can use a SARIMAX model in my case with d=0 (no differencing) but with a seasonal component. Is my understanding correct? However I would still like to know if a dataset can be stationary as well as show seasonality and why.